# How to reference host environment variable values in Docker-compose when using env_file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, env-file

I'm currently deploying an application using Docker-compose and using `env_file` for managing environment variables. I'd like to reference the value of a specific environment variable from the host's environment in my `env_file`.

How can I configure this?

For example, let's assume the following scenario: there is an environment variable called `MY_SECRET_KEY` on the host, and I want to use this value in the `env_file` of Docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp:latest
    env_file:
      - .my.env
```

.my.env:

```
API_KEY=${MY_SECRET_KEY}
```

Container config Env:

```
$ docker inspect myapp | jq '.[].Config.Env'
[
  ...
  "API_KEY=${MY_SECRET_KEY}",
  ...
]
```

In the above setup, is there a way to make `${MY_SECRET_KEY}` in the .my.env file reference the value of `MY_SECRET_KEY` from the host?

Comment: Some basic experimentation with Compose suggests this works the way you expect; also see [Syntax for environment files in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/env-file/).  (`docker run --env-file` does not support substitution though.)  When you `docker inspect` at the end, are you sure you're inspecting the container and not the image?